# ACPI BIOS Error messages when booting Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, bios, acpi

After upgrading my ASUS Zenbook UX305UA (Intel i5-6200) from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 (20.04.1 LTS to be specific) a couple of weeks ago, I am experiencing odd bugs. While odd green pixels like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04) were cured by uninstalling `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, I am still experiencing kernel errors when booting:

```
[0.223364] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-303)
[0.223479] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[0.240043] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[0.240156] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[0.285219] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[0.285224] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[0.514783] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not over the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[0.514943] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed4mm80 f80
```

Searching stackexchange/askubuntu, I came across [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233019/kernel-error-messages-when-booting-ubuntu-20-04) confirming that it is a glinch in the BIOS and this is pretty much where my expertise comes to an end (very fast^^). @heynnema's answer sounded a good start but didn't work out (they suggested to roll back grub temporarily checking if the error still occurs at other kernels. However, I can't even boot up in kernel *5.4.0-54* -- where *-56* is my normal kernel.) My BIOS is older than in the mentioned post:

```
BIOS Vendor     American Megatrends
Version         201
VBIOS Version   1024.I019UX204UA.003
EC Version      FOSL0900
```

The next newer (and current) version is [302](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX305UA/HelpDesk_BIOS/), which does "Optimize system performance". I am playing with the thought of upgrading the BIOS -- though I have never done this before.

*The problem* are not the errors/warnings but that the system crashes at irregular times when being suspended. It boots up again automatically (instead from resuming from suspending) and runs straight into the safety/boot-option mode. I click "ubuntu" and it remains in a back screen forever (OK, I didn't try "forever", but its longer than I ever kept my patience). I have to force another boot (again into the safety/boot-option menu) but this time, ubuntu boots up.

**EDIT/Update**
Here is the output of `/var/log/syslog`. I found a couple of suspicious entries but I can't figure that out.

```
kernel: [    0.044436] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
kernel: [    0.044438] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.
kernel: [    0.066629] Memory: 7958792K/8282176K available (14339K kernel code, 2426K rwdata, 4932K rodata, 2720K init, 4956K bss, 323384K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
kernel: [    0.066636] random: get_random_u64 called from kmem_cache_open+0x2d/0x410 with crng_init=0

kernel: [    0.205091] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
kernel: [    0.205132] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
kernel: [    0.206128] ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
systemd[1]: Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
kernel: [    0.209596] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.209781] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.209967] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.210151] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
kernel: [    0.210333] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.210553] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.210738] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
kernel: [    0.210923] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.211108] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.211291] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.211759] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
kernel: [    0.211969] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.212153] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.212335] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.212521] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
apparmor.systemd[823]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
kernel: [    0.212709] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.212890] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.213078] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.213262] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.213446] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
kernel: [    0.223256] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
kernel: [    0.223369] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_STA]
kernel: [    0.223369] No Arguments are initialized for method [_STA]
kernel: [    0.223371] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
apparmor.systemd[824]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
kernel: [    0.226734] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-fe])
kernel: [    0.226740] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
systemd[1]: Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
kernel: [    0.228690] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
kernel: [    0.228691] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
kernel: [    0.229619] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00

systemd[1]: Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
kernel: [    0.240047] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
kernel: [    0.240158] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_STA]
kernel: [    0.240159] No Arguments are initialized for method [_STA]
kernel: [    0.240160] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
systemd[1]: Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
kernel: [    0.240363] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
kernel: [    0.240442] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
kernel: [    0.240520] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
kernel: [    0.240597] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
kernel: [    0.240673] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
kernel: [    0.240749] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
kernel: [    0.240825] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
kernel: [    0.240902] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
kernel: [    0.241685] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
kernel: [    0.241685] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
kernel: [    0.241699] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_: GPE=0x50, IRQ=-1, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
systemd[1]: Starting Accounts Service...
kernel: [    0.241700] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions and events

systemd[1]: Starting Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
kernel: [    0.289553] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
kernel: [    0.289666] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_STA]
systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
kernel: [    0.289667] No Arguments are initialized for method [_STA]
kernel: [    0.289668] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
kernel: [    0.290298] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 9 devices

kernel: [    0.592224] platform eisa.0: Probing EISA bus 0
kernel: [    0.592225] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
kernel: [    0.592227] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
kernel: [    0.592228] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
kernel: [    0.592229] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
kernel: [    0.592229] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
kernel: [    0.592230] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
kernel: [    0.592231] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
kernel: [    0.592232] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
kernel: [    0.592233] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
kernel: [    0.592234] platform eisa.0: EISA: Detected 0 cards

kernel: [    0.994749] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
kernel: [    0.994764] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_STA]
kernel: [    0.994766] No Arguments are initialized for method [_STA]
kernel: [    0.994768] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
kernel: [    1.003201] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
kernel: [    1.003202] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
kernel: [    1.007198] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
kernel: [    1.008143] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
kernel: [    1.015015] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
kernel: [    1.015371] idma64 idma64.1: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
kernel: [    1.019523] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
kernel: [    1.019534] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_STA]
kernel: [    1.019536] No Arguments are initialized for method [_STA]
kernel: [    1.019537] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
kernel: [    1.021306] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0100:00: i2c-ELAN0100:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
kernel: [    1.021318] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0100:00: i2c-ELAN0100:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
kernel: [    1.058858] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20190822 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
kernel: [    1.064944] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
kernel: [    1.068602] acpi device:0f: registered as cooling_device4

kernel: [    1.878751] systemd-fstab-generator[382]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
kernel: [    1.880453] systemd[373]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1.
kernel: [    2.969328] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
kernel: [    2.979913] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/vpnagentd.service:10: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/vpnagentd.pid → /run/vpnagentd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
kernel: [    2.981045] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/teamviewerd.pid → /run/teamviewerd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
```

Comment: If there are no other problems with the system, no need to mess with the BIOS. Additionally messing with the BIOS could break your system

Comment: fair point @SerialGamer, and I usually wouldn't care too much about what is raised at startup when everything is normal afterwards but the system repeatedly crashes. I added a paragraph at the end of the question to describe the problem. Thx

Comment: Do you see anything noteworthy in /var/log/apport.log or in /var/log/syslog

Comment: thy @darth_epoxy. I guess not (as far as I can assess this but I am not sure what to look for -- in `/var/log/syslog`, the other does not exist). A few network and anti-virus warnings/errors but nothing I can link to the BIOS or the startup in general

Comment: Well a starting point would be to note the exact date/time of a crash and then search the log for an event at that exact timestamp. Also a big crash would show as a file in ~/var/crash/ but don't be surprised if that directory is empty.

Comment: @darth_epoxy man are that a bunch of rows. I did my best in narrowing down but I could need some help^^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find acpi drivers for specific acpi device / Solving kernel suspend bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198969/how-to-find-acpi-drivers-for-specific-acpi-device-solving-kernel-suspend-bug)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: No, since I actually did a BIOS update. Interestingly, the error vanished when upgrading to 22.04

Comment: "The problem are not the errors/warnings"  Not according to the title, Pleas e fix that or lots of people will ONLY comment on the title.

Comment: Not Sure but can you check your /etc/fstab. There systemd hast maybe a Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I went in rescue mode, made some free space and ran `apt-get clean`. Then I selected the option to boot normally and Ubuntu 22.04 started.
Mibi88

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but after investigating, I've concluded that in absence of a real problem, this message is a poorly label "warning".

Based on "dmesg" logging labels, it is an "err" but not an "alert" nor it is "crit(ical)". Ignore it.