# /var/log/kern.log growing out of hand

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, log

I don't know much about linux so I was wondering if I could get a bit of help with this (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS):

I just got a message that my ssd is running out of space and when going through my folder, the culprit seem to be the /var/log folder. I have a 96GB kern.log.1 file and a 49GB kern.log file and a bunch of other ~500MB .gz files filled with those log entries:

```
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665624] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L6F.PGRT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665628] 
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665629] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L6F]
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665630] 
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665630] No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665631] 
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665632] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.665635] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20210331/evgpe-511)
May  8 08:17:29 nico-desktop kernel: [  145.666948] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L6F.PGRT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
```

It seems like my system is writing this message over and over hundreds of times per minutes. Can I delete those files or do something about it?
update: from what I've gathered with google, kern.log.1 is an already archived log that I could safely delete. I've done a logrotate and changed the config file to logrotate automatically at 1GB in size. That temporary fix allows me to have disk space back so my computer can work but the log is still growing by 50-100mb/minute so if anyone know a fix to my error message, that would be very kind of you :)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1117992/acpi-exception-ae-not-found-while-evaluating-gpe-method-floods-syslog

Comment: update: from what I've gathered with google, kern.log.1 is an already archived log that I could safely delete. I've done a logrotate and changed the config file to logrotate automatically at 1GB in size.
That temporary fix allows me to have disk space back so my computer can work but the log is still growing by 50-100mb/minute so if anyone know a fix to my error message, that would be very kind of you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved it, it looks like the problem was coming from the bios. updating it fixed the issue. Thank you chili555 for the help.

Comment: Welcome to AU. In 2 days you can accept your own answer. That will get you 15 reputation points.

Comment: Wrong - you don't get rep for accepting your own answer. Also, this technically doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu, and is unlikely to help anyone else. So this topic might be closed as off-topic.