# Log files won't stop writing error messages

Tags: syslog

It's my first time with Ubuntu 22.04.

I've re-done a format, because previously, log files such as `syslog` and `kern.log` (at `/var/log`) kept writing the same error messages (I suppose) and fulled my hard drive. The messages were about the same as in [this case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409275/var-log-kern-log-growing-out-of-hand).

I deleted them, but the machine kept going slowly. I opened the the System Monitor and saw that a `gnome-shell` was using most of my CPU. I killed it, and the UI disappeared; I knew I had messed up.

At the moment I'm typing from a fresh install, but I'm afraid this uncontrolled spam will begin sooner or later. What should I do? I've read it might have to do with BIOS, but I don't want to mess it up; better just follow the advice of some expert.

Edit: I solved this problem by replacing line:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3 vga=current pcie_aspm=off"` in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: The usual recommended solution is to *fix the actual problem* that is being repeatedly logged. Since you have not presented actual log output, we don't know if you have the same problem (which was indeed fixed) or not.

Comment: From the link you refers to it seems that the advise from the expert is to see if there is a update to the motherboard bios / firmware from the vendor ... have you checked that ?

Comment: @SorenA, how do I check this in Ubuntu?

Comment: @BestQualityVacuum you check it at your motherboard vendor's homepage.