# Error while booting in Ubunt 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, bios, acpi

[Error while booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEe4x.jpg)

I am getting this Error while booting into my ubuntu 20.04 version

```
[   0.241437] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol R_SB.PCIO.P02],
AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[   0.241449] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps object-220) 
[   0.549585] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 
[   0.708855] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol (\_SB.PCIO.GP17.VGA.LCD._8CM.RFN7], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[   0.708990] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB,PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529) 
/devinvmelnlp6: clean, 1442061/16251840 files, 46563155/64858880 blocks
```

It just happened recently (i was not getting it before)
It is really annoying and slowing the booting process
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: How do you know it is slowing booting?

Comment: No, it always happened but maybe quicly so you didn't notice it before. And no, it doesn't slow the boot process. And, as usual, update UEFI ("BIOS") before anything else. If the messages persist then there's nothing else to do except wait for a kernel update that handles this specific firmware quirks.

Answer (score 1):

I have laptop Lenovo V15 G2 ITL.

I have dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 11.

I have the same error, that appeared recently, I guess after system update in Ubuntu, maybe a week ago..

I choose advance boot in the grub boot menu, where options are:
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-41-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-41-generic (recovery)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic (recovery)

If I choose Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-41-generic I get described error,
but when I choose Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic, system boots without errors.

I guess error has to be with newer/newest kernel.

BR

Comment: Ok but after rebooting it returns by default to kernel 5.15.0-41
So I guess you have to choose 5.13.0.52 every single time
which which is inconvenient

Is there a possibility for this error to be fixed in the near future? :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the newest kernel. If you still have the previous kernel, then choose it at boot time and see if the error went away.

To choose the previous kernel press and hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> button while booting.

Comment: This is not a bug in a kernel. Ubuntu maintainers could hide these mesagges not to disturb users, but still there is nothing to be fixed in a kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6: really? https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213023

Comment: It is a matter of opinions. Anyway these messages do not mean much.

Comment: how to choose the previous kernel?

Comment: Confirmed as a kernel bug by that link.

Comment: @AhmedEmad: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, Thanks so much

Comment: I have tried with pressing SHIFT but it didn't work
I am using ubuntu with windows dual boot