# Ubuntu showing few errors while start up

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on dual boot with Windows 10 on an HP laptop with old configurations. I have been using Ubuntu for the past few months now, but recently I see some errors popping up after I select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu. I don't know what these errors imply, however after showing the error for 4-5 seconds Ubuntu boots up normally.

How do I resolve these errors? I'm worried that this might be indicative of some bigger problem in future if not resolved. I am highly dependent on Ubuntu as Windows is very laggy on my laptop.

Errors that showed up:

[image]

Comment: I think you can safely ignore it, but, if not, the errors seem to be coming from your BIOS, not from Ubuntu itself

Comment: Probably nothing to worry about if the system boots normally but in case when asking here (or anywhere else) make sure to provide all the relevant information. Saying "I see some errors" without identifying them is vague and makes the question unanswerable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have attached a link to the image showing the errors. Please see it. I can't exactly understand what the error is about, that's why I pasted the link.

Comment: As expected, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)