# I restarted my computer while it was getting ready to update. Now I receive an ACPI BIOS Error everytime I boot up. How do I fix this?

Tags: boot, acpi

Okay, so this happened a few days ago. I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on an HP Pavilion x360 laptop and I've got my system set to check for updates weekly and I always update when I'm prompted to with zero issue via the Update Manager. However, unlike all the other times that I've updated in the past, the "Authentication Required" prompt didn't pop up immediately after the updates were downloaded until a few hours later when I minimized one of my windows and saw the prompt popped up in the lefthand corner like in the picture below.
[image: Picture of my desktop 30 minutes before I decided to restart my laptop. The Authentication prompt is in the top left hand corner, password was typed in, and the "Authenticate" button is greyed out.]

After asking a few of my friends if they've seen anything like this before, I decided (stupidly) to bite the bullet and restart my laptop hoping that it'd fix whatever was going on. While the system seems to boot up properly whenever I restart my laptop (as in I can still log into Ubuntu and use my computer as normal), the first thing that pops up is this line of code that I can't really make heads or tails of.

```
[ 0.492230] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.CRG], AE_NOT_Found (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.492298] ACPI Error: Aborting method \PNOT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[ 0.492324] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.LPCB.ECO._Reg due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
/dev/sda2: clean, 763655/7782400 files, 23502823/3127296 blocks
[ 3.974764] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 3.974B06] sd 1:0:0:0: [sbd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4.800323] scsi 1:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
[ 4.800372] scsi 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[ 4.800404] scsi 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
```

I'm not entirely sure about that last line of code since I rewrote everything from a picture I took of my screen as it was booting up, but everything else lines up. Is there any way that I can fix this without having to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: This is not a problem, errors at boot are normal and safe to ignore, assuming everything seems to be working properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: The thing is that these errors have never popped up for me before. Especially not every time I reboot my system. I'm just trying to understand what's going on here.

Edit: Looked at the thread... I don't think it answers my question. I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 since it came out and I've never had these errors pop up before the "update fail".

Comment: Possibly one of the updates that was installed was a kernel update, which could cause these to appear suddenly.

Comment: Also that wasn't necessarily an update fail, how do you know it failed? It downloaded updates, asked for authentication. Seems fine to me.

Comment: The thing is that I don't really know IF the update failed. I don't really know how to explain it better than the "Authentication Required" prompt just... didn't disappear after I entered my password like it normally does. It just stayed in the top left corner until I restarted my laptop. There was no "installing/finalizing updates" box like normal.

Comment: hmm, kinda weird. You can try updating manually (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`) and see if you get any weird errors. But I would assume everything is fine, the update worked (even though it looked strange) and the errors you see now are normal (apparently a lot of people are having them now with the newer kernel, but if everything seems to work normally it's fine).

Comment: Alright, decided to manually update just to see if it made a difference. As far as I can tell: nothing weird popped up in the terminal and everything's up to date. Even though I still don't completely understand what those errors mean, I'm relieved to know that they (probably) aren't caused by something I did.

Comment: The suggested duplicate above (2nd comment) explains what those "errors" are. And FYI, since a long time ago, the updater only requires password for kernel updates. And you should be at 20.04.4 by now if the updates are correct. To make sure repeat the process but with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` instead.