# How to get rid of this ACPI Error?

Tags: kernel, acpi

I am using Ubuntu linux version 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP. I started getting the following errors after a power failure that occurred during shutdown.  The shutdown procedure was not completed at the time of power failure.  Since then these errors show up at every start up.

```
14:07:40 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - SATA (20210730/dspkginit-438
14:08:08 kernel: Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
```

My laptop details are:
Toshiba Satellite L650
Processor Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz × 4
RAM 4GB

Is there a way to get rid of the above errors ?  Please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: It is not related to power failure, but with the upgrade to the 5.15 kernel and a poor ACPI table.

Comment: Thank you, Pilot6.  Does comment 2 mean that when the kernel gets updated/upgraded next the error is likely to go away ?

Comment: It may be fixed sometime, but it is not guaranteed. You can try to upgrade BIOS. The problem is not with the kernel, but with your UEFI. Kernel started showing it.

Comment: Or, will it go away if I install the new Ubuntu version 22.04 as fresh installation, replacing the current version ?

Comment: Mine is legacy HDD boot loader.  2011 model laptop.  BIOS software may not be available for uprgrade.  Any suggestion ?

Comment: So ignore this.