# How to solve "ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element" after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, acpi

I get this error after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04:

```
[    1.232426] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference packa
ge element - \_PR_.P000 (20210730/dspkginit-428)
/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 252743/13959168 files, 4722829/55832576 blocks
```

Here is a photo of the error message:

[image: ACPI Error]

After this error the system continues to boot properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)