# ACPI Error when booting

Tags: boot, uefi, acpi

This is the error I get:

```
[1.035999] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PROO._CPC] ,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[1.036003] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Aborting method \_SB.PR10._CPC due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1.036025] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PROO._CPC] ,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[1.036030] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Aborting method \_SB.PR11._CPC due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1.036052] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PROO._CPC] ,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[1.036057] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Aborting method \_SB.PR12._CPC due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1.036079] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PROO._CPC] ,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[1.036083] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Aborting method \_SB.PR13._CPC due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1.036105] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PROO._CPC] ,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[1.036110] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Aborting method \_SB.PR14._CPC due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1.036131] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PROO._CPC] ,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[1.036136] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Aborting method \_SB.PR15._CPC due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check root delay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  UUID=21b981ae-445d-43e5-95ae-6aa5d01337a5 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Comment: This is Ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64, previously the computer was running windows 10. I installed from the iso over the old windows.

Comment: The ACPI errors are probably nothing to worry about. It appears that for some reason the UUID specified in your /etc/fstab file is wrong. You could look at correcting it or specifying in a different way but if this is a new installation that has never booted correctly I’d just reinstall

Comment: This error has been popping up a lot recently since the latest kernel upgrade. Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)