# My laptop is not booting it's stuck and getting an ACPI Error

Tags: boot, windows, bootloader, boot-repair

My laptop is not booting. It's stuck at a black screen and getting an ACPI Error.

```
Error: Abortion method  
ACPI BIOS Error Could not resolve symbol AE_NOT_FOUND
ACPI Error
```

[image: The text on this image says BIOS Error Could not resolve symbol l, AE NOT FOUND ACPI Error]

Comment: is this all the information you want to share with us? no os-no flavour-no laptop-no desktop-no cpu-no memory-no new or old install-no information about what you have tried to do to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)