# ACPI bios error - Dell Vostro 15 3000

Tags: boot

I am getting ACPI bios error on Dell Vostro 15 3000. I upgrade the bios and edit the grub for noacpi, acpi=off and the error still continue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Bottom line: The parameters you added only made it worse.