# ACPI errors on boot

Tags: boot, 22.04

I get these error messages on boot. I cannot tell what they pertain to. My machine is a Fujistu Esprimo D956. This is a new install of 22.04.

[image: bootup erros]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Not sure. I just updated to the most recent UEFI. Errors persist. Should I check my SSD? What do they mean exactly?