# Help understanding logs on Ubuntu 20.04 startup

Tags: 20.04, bios

I've recently been getting these logs every time I turn on my laptop. It doesn't seem to jeopardize performance, but I'd like to make them disappear, and possibly understand a little bit of what it is about.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: There are 2 kinds of messages - ACPI messages and orphaned inode messages. Do you get both types on all reboots? The ACPI message is a known issue, the orphaned inode should hopefully not persist (unless the computer shut down in the middle of a disk operation).