# How to fix the problem shown in the picture with Ubuntu 22?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 22.04, error-handling, screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oZVc.jpg)Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 22, a message appear while booting the OS

Comment: Generally, the way to fix things is get the source code, study it, fix bugs, recompile. I think a BIOS update could help. You might want to show us the output of `dmesg | grep -i acpi`, not the screenshot, just the text itself.

Comment: You can almost always ignore such errors.

Comment: Yes I can ignore it. But I always try to discover the reason behind the problem.i will try to update the bios

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)