# ACPI BIOS Error Aborting Method

Tags: boot, 22.04

I have dual PC-Ubuntu system and I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. My Ubuntu system is booting up but I get this error codes while booting.

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol

ACPI Error: Aborting method

mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

[image: please see screenshot]

I am not sure what is the problem. I came across other posts in the community where folks have troubling installing ubuntu or the system does not boot; my system works just fine apart from the error codes while booting. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: error codes while booting are perfectly fine and safe and nothing to worry about if your system is otherwise working as expected.

Comment: I agree with Esther with 1 addition: the newer kernel show more errors where before those got suppressed (as the kernel did not probe for them or where all mistakes got ignored).  These are for kernel developers and/or your bios manufacturer to fix (the 1st will happen in time; the 2nd would require a bios update; risky so feel free to ignore these errors).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all. Will not do anything