# Kubuntu 22.04 Randomly Reboots when I press FN+F5

Tags: kubuntu, bios, reboot, acpi

FN+F5 is my volume up key on my keyboard.  I use it all the time, but every now and then, when I press it, my computer goes black and reboots.  It doesn't give me a splash screen to confirm that I want to restart, it just reboots at that instant.  I'm thinking it has something to do with these issues below (My computer is an Acer Nitro 5 Spin laptop):

[ACPI BIOS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxeel.jpg)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the errors in your image, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot Can you paste output from `journalctl` starting from shortly before the system reboots, so we can see what's happening when it decides to reboot? use https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ if there are a lot of lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know how to recreate the random boot. All I know is that it happens occasionally when I press the fn+f5 key.

Comment: Ok, so next time it randomly reboots, get the output from right before the system shut off and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425243/edit) your question to add it. Or find the output from whenever you took the image you attached.

Comment: Ok so it just happened.  I clicked volume up and ran journalctl strictly after it. The journalctl output is here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/pTdCbRQz5Y/.  I was using google chrome, and then pressed volume up when the reboot happened. Thank you! @Esther

Comment: I have the same issue and found [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/xhjfgd/kubuntu_2204_session_logoutends_when_i_hit_the/).  TLDR: It's a known bug in xserver that is apparently fixed but the fix is not adopted by 22.04.  Apparently reducing the repeat rate in the keyboard settings can make it at least less likely to occur.