# So many errors when booting up Ubuntu in dual boot?

Tags: acpi, nouveau, firmware

I have my pc dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04. Ever since I installed Ubuntu 22.04 I am getting so many errors and my booting up is so slow. Could uninstalling both operating systems and then fresh installing Ubuntu(in UEFI, currently I think it is installed as legacy) solve the problem?

[Errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBm35.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Also install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: And although UEFI should be the preferred method for any mainstream OS since a decade ago, what you showed here is unrelated.