# ubuntu 20.04 voice recording not working inside applications

Tags: drivers, sound, microphone, audio-recording, sound-recorder

I am trying to do a Google Meet session
inside the browser the voice is not recorded but when I try to use sound recorder it works
I am using the internal mic
I have ubuntu 20.04 on lenovo ideapad 330
I tried to use external usb sound card  and it worked perfectly, does that mean that my sound card is not working or needs replacment?
**NOTE:** the problem began when I added a new ram for my machine.

Comment: the boot errors are not related at all, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot

Comment: @Esther so is those errors related to the new ram?