# Errors on bootscreen

Tags: boot, kubuntu, macbook-pro

Recently installed my first Ubuntu to an old MacBook Pro (unibody mid2012) and it has been working smooth aside from some errors that flash during the boot screen. This is my first experience with Linux I’m pretty new to the system but I’m decent at figuring things out. As far as the errors they’re more of a nuisance I don’t think they’re related to any real failures . Please see attached below I’ve searched and haven’t found any concrete info on this . Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Error message:

```
0.117546] DMAR-IR: [Firmware Bug]: loapic 2 has no mapping iommu, interrupt remapping will be disabled
0.195847] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found (Integer) 0000000035075d57 (20210730/exresop-66)
0.195858] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for (St pre) (20210730/dswexec-431)
0.195880] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPUO._PDC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

Comment: I think so too: the errors they’re more of a nuisance I don’t think they’re related to any real failures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)