# Laptop won't start with ACPI error

Tags: boot, 20.04, hp, acpi, hp-pavilion

I recently bought an HP pavilion aero 13 laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. Everything seems to be installed, but there is a problem. When I turn on my laptop, I get this error:

```
[0.6146781] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_PR_.P000 (20210738/dspkginit-438)

[1.062788] pcie_mp2_amd 0000:03:00.7: amd_sfh_hid_client_init failed

/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 176580/31227904 files, 4413085/124895488 blocks
```

Then it quickly disappears, then more text appears, quickly disappears and the Ubuntu boot screen appears.

After that, there are two options. First - the system does not boot for a very long time. The second one loads, but at some point it freezes while working and I turn off the laptop by long pressing the power button.

Can you please tell me what could be causing this and how to fix it?
If possible, then I need the fastest way, since I have an urgent job. Thank you!

Comment: The ACPI error is benign and does not stop your boot nor does it extends the time booting. It is a mismatch between your BIOS and kernel. MOST of us have it (I have 6 of them)  The problem will be with the NEXT thing that is done AFTER the `/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 176580/31227904 files, 4413085/124895488 blocks`.  Check your boot log, systemd boot analyze and/or  /var/log/ for notices

Comment: what kernel? `linux-intel-5.13/5.13.0-1010.10` should fix `amd_sfh_hid_client_init failed`

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried ```sudo less /var/log/boot.log``` but didn't see anything

Comment: I reinstalled the system again, but this time I did not install any updates. While everything works. Is it possible that these problems are due to updates? (last time I immediately installed all the updates and after rebooting the laptop the problems started)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @Pilot6, No, but thanks for the tip

Comment: @karel No, but thanks for the tip