# Screen flickering between comand prompt and company logo while startup in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, laptop, screen

Details : OS : Ubuntu 22.04
Graphics : radeon Graphics
Problem : while startup screen is flickring between logo and comand prompt.
[image]

While turning on laptop it start happening[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)