# AE_NOT_FOUND on bootup - just ignore or try to resolve?

Tags: acpi

My 22.04 system works, but on bootup, I get the following errors (taken from dmesg file).

The main issue is `AE_NOT_FOUND` and `AE_ALREADY_EXISTS`. It seems, from basic searching, that this is some issue with the ACPI which is the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface. My impression is that it's best just to tolerate these errors and not to try to resolve them.

This happens every time I bootup and has been happening for weeks. I don't know how or why it started.

```
[ 0.135015] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.TXHC.RHUB.SS01], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)

[ 0.135022] kernel: fbcon: Taking over console

[ 0.135028] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135031] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)

[ 0.135033] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.TXHC.RHUB.SS02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)

[ 0.135036] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135038] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)

[ 0.135040] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.TXHC.RHUB.SS03], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)

[ 0.135043] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135044] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)

[ 0.135046] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.TXHC.RHUB.SS04], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)

[ 0.135049] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135050] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)

[ 0.135053] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135056] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135058] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135059] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135062] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135064] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135192] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135195] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135197] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135198] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135201] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135203] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135205] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135208] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135210] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135211] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135214] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135216] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135286] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135290] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135292] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135293] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135296] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135297] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135300] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135302] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135304] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135306] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135308] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135310] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135312] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135315] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135317] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135318] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135321] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135323] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135325] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135328] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135330] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135331] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135334] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135336] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135338] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135341] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135343] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135344] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135346] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135348] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135475] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135478] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135480] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135481] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135484] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135486] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135610] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135613] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135615] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135616] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135619] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135621] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135745] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135748] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135750] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135751] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135754] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135756] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135759] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135761] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135763] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135764] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135767] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135769] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135771] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135774] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135776] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135777] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135780] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135782] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135784] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135787] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135789] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135790] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135793] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135795] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135797] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135799] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135801] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135803] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135805] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135807] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135809] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135812] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135814] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.135815] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)

[ 0.135818] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.135820] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)

[ 0.138047] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPD0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)

[ 0.138051] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.138053] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)

[ 0.138072] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)

[ 0.138075] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)

[ 0.138077] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)

[ 0.139270] kernel: ACPI: 15 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded

[ 0.146859] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.146867] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC02F1A00 0001C6 (v02 PmRef Cpu0Psd 00003000 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.147638] kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PR00: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked

[ 0.152838] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.152844] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC125E000 000386 (v02 PmRef Cpu0Cst 00003001 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.153740] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.153746] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC1283800 0005C3 (v02 PmRef Cpu0Ist 00003000 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.154727] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.154731] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC1258800 000266 (v02 PmRef Cpu0Hwp 00003000 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.155773] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.155779] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC007F000 0008E7 (v02 PmRef ApIst 00003000 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.156795] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.156800] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC1282800 00048A (v02 PmRef ApHwp 00003000 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.157730] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.157735] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC1286800 0004D4 (v02 PmRef ApPsd 00003000 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.158657] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[ 0.158662] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF893AC1284000 00048A (v02 PmRef ApCst 00003000 INTL 20160422)

[ 0.167725] kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started

[ 0.167726] kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked

[ 0.167988] kernel: ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62

[ 0.167989] kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PC00.LPCB.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions

[ 0.167990] kernel: ACPI: Interpreter enabled

[ 0.168031] kernel: ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)

[ 0.168031] kernel: ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing

[ 0.168066] kernel: PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (base 0xc0000000)

[ 0.176290] kernel: PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved in ACPI motherboard resources

[ 0.176299] kernel: PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug

[ 0.176300] kernel: PCI: Using E820 reservations for host bridge windows

[ 0.181102] kernel: ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 7F

[ 0.181623] kernel: ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PCRP]

[ 0.181650] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.DGPV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[ 0.181655] kernel:

[ 0.181656] kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_ON_]

[ 0.181657] kernel:

[ 0.181657] kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [_ON_]

[ 0.181657] kernel:

[ 0.181658] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG0.PCRP._ON due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1333162/15811

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, I suppose it does. The thing I found strange was that the error messages just started for some reason. However, as that link states: "If this error didn't occurred in the past, but now it does, it may be because you use a new Linux kernel, you changed your BIOS/UEFI or your hardware fails." Presumably, the kernel was updated because I certainly didn't change any BIOS settings. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: No problem. Kernel 5.13 seems to have introduced these a lot more.