# Hi am a new user of Ubuntu and while instaling i have some small problems

Tags: boot, software-installation, hp

I have an HP Pavilion laptop with intel i7 and 8 GB RAM and a GeForce GTX 1080 graphics card.

I download the Ubuntu installer, and I booted it. I completed the setup 2 times and I still got an error. Here's the error.

[image: Here's an image of the error]

```
[ 0.068039] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[ 0.068043] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[ 0.548357] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.P EGO.PEGP. ON], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)
[ 0.548367] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202210 20/psobject-220)
[ 0.548374] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.P EGO.PEGP._OFF], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)
[ 0.548380] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202210 20/psobject-220)
[ 1.056179] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.SPI1.FPNT. CRS due to previ ous error (AE_AML_INVALID_RESOURCE_TYPE) (20221020/psparse-529)
I 1.056191] ACPI Error: Method execution failed \_SB.PCIO.SPI1.FPNT. CRS due to previous error (AE_AML_INVALID_RESOURCE_TYPE) (20221020/uteval-68)
[ 1.064099] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.SP12.FPNT. CRS due to previ ous error (AE_AML_INVALID_RESOURCE_TYPE) (20221020/psparse-529)
[ 1.064110] ACPI Error: Method execution failed \_SB.PCIO.SP12.FPNT. CRS due to previous error (AE_AML_INVALID_RESOURCE_TYPE) (20221020/uteval-68) /dev/mapper/vgcutefishos-root: clean, 273487/60891136 files, 6989154/243557376 b
```

Comment: Duplicate with [AE_NOT_FOUND on bootup - just ignore or try to resolve?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428948/ae-not-found-on-bootup-just-ignore-or-try-to-resolve),  which refers to: [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot/1333162#1333162)

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough information on your system, however

it appears you need to do just what the first two lines are implying, that is boot up your computer, enter BIOS setup mode, then:

1. enable VMX ( Virtual Machine Extensions )
2. enable SGX ( Software Guard Extension )

for issue one, see more here [VMX (outside TXT) : disabled by bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297433/vmx-outside-txt-disabled-by-bios)

and for issue number two, take a look here [SGX disabled by BIOS in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406760/sgx-disabled-by-bios-in-ubuntu-22-04)

after that do a clean install, **wipe previous installation**.

hopefully, you'll have Ubuntu running soon.

Comment: the 1st 2 are comments by the kernel and are perfectly normal. no need to alter settingds. Please don't use other questions on AU to refer too as that makes this a duplicate. it is to normal action to vote to close against a dupe

Comment: @Rinzwind this not exactly a duplicate and the user is **new**, are you certain SGX disabled isn't triggering the ACPI BIOS errors ?

Comment: yes. we ALL have these ACPI errors. Those are not for us but for bios manufacturers and kernel developers. Started to show with kernel 5.19 (where the logging was set to also show these notices) but these have always been there.

Comment: @Rinzwind I am sorry, I have the impression that this user is unable to boot up, not just receiving errors. otherwise, why would he install twice ? if not, you're right.

Comment: "small problems"? it says ;-) and if there is a booting problem  the problem is the line NOT shown (so next after these), Printed line:s on screen means the boot continued ;-) The next thing the system tests after this is the video card driver (oh and there are only two big issues that stop a boot: hardware failure or video card driver failure; the 1st shows a clear error; the 2nd stops the boot).

Comment: so he is able to boot or not ?

Comment: I did all of this and i cant boot to Ubuntu heres the screen shots [VMX](http://https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1018425188381118496/1155537864776503296/IMG_0563.jpg) [SGX](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1018425188381118496/1155537866680709170/IMG_0561.jpg) tell me if i did something wrong

Comment: your VMX screenshot isn't opening. have you tried re-installing/re-formatting your hard drive ?

Comment: also, try to set your BIOS "Clear TPM" to 'clear'

Comment: this is a BIOS issue. Microsoft has done it's best to push manufacturers to lock into windows, secure boots, tpms etc. what's your laptop's model ?