# Strange errors while booting the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, bios, acpi

As I remember after installing Jellyfish Ubuntu OS, strange messages appeared during booting the OS, they saying about some BIOS bug, and device name error as I understand. Actually I have a PATA SSD (with my Ubuntu) attached to SATA port with adapter, may be this causes bugs and errors... But after these messages the Ubuntu loads up and all works great. What should I do with this? Or simply ignore it? Are these errors and bugs are critical? Hope that someone will help me... Or may be someone will write me what is it all about with this errors and bugs... Thank You very much in advance, guys! Have a nice day!

The messages are these:

[0.134910] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS

[0.134914] ×86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.

[0.351101] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PRO0._CPC],

AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[0.351115] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR01._CPC due to previous error

(AE_NOT_FOUND)(20210730/psparse-529)

[0.351156] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PRO0._CPC],

AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[0.351165] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PRO2._CPC due to previous error

(AE_NOT_FOUND)(20210730/psparse-529)

[0.351205] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol (_PR.PROO._CPC],

AE_NOT_FOUND(20210730/psargs-330)

[0.351214] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR03._CPC due to previous error

(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)

dev/sdb2: clean, 219869/3850240 files, 3553429/15398912 blocks

[3.056259] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

Comment: Did you search this site for other questions regarding those errors?

Comment: I have the same errors on some older home made PC I just ignore them.

Comment: No, I did not search for this problem on this site. As I do not smart in all this deep nerd computer things… I took a more simple way… If someone already knows this problem and can tell the solution… This is my hope. Thank You anyway!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Yes! It’s OK! I think I can accept it as an answer. Thank You! I posted it as an answer in the underneath.