# x86/cpu sgx disabled by bios

Tags: 22.04, intel

[**error message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4aNr.jpg)

how do I disable this error. I don't want to fix it, I just don't want to see it.I use an Asus ROG(G752VM) laptop.
cpu: Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: It is not really an error it is an info message. There is noting to fix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: you can add "quiet splash" to your GRUB command line in order to not see *any* messages at boot, if you want that.

Comment: i already added the "quiet splash" to grub. In fact, that was the default. but the message keeps showing every time i boot up.

Comment: Again, there's nothing to fix. Situation may change in the future with an UEFI update and/or new kernel. Meanwhile ignore it like everybody else.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice.