# Kernel Log Errors

Tags: kernel, crash

I am getting some kernel log errors and my system sometimes crashes to green screen and I am wondering if it could be related to those errors.

I got Ubuntu 22.04.1 installed with Kernel 5.19.5.x. Hardware AMD® Ryzen 7 4800u with radeon graphics × 16

sudo dmesg --level=emerg,alert,crit,err

```
[    0.312589] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\SMIB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dsfield-637)
[    0.314468] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dswload2-162)
[    0.314473] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
[    1.057276] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
[    7.151168] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[    7.170093] Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8
[    9.062833] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[    9.160204] Dev loop21: unable to read RDB block 8
```

The first one, I think is a know bug, but I am not sure about the others.

------------------------------------update----------

After clean fresh install of 22.04.1 with default kernel 5.15.0.48 generic it looks like this:

```
[    0.328465] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\SMIB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-637)
[    0.330336] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[    0.330341] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.460841] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
[    6.337538] pcie_mp2_amd 0000:05:00.7: amd_sfh_hid_client_init failed
```

Comment: Does this happen with an Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: There is just one linux kernel right?

Comment: The `5.19.5` is not an Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: How do you find out which version is an Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: These kernel messages are not related to any crash. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot

Comment: Thanks you, that helps

Comment: Also there is a new BIOS Version F09 for Gigabyte Boards, I installed it today and it files smoother :) Probably they fixed some stuff regarding the GPUs

Comment: Still crashing to green screen ^^