# How do I fix a boot error after 22.04 upgrade?

Tags: boot

A boot error message has begun showing up on my laptop since I upgraded to the current 22.04.1 LTS release. I had previously been running the 20.04 release. The error message that appears on my laptop screen right after I power up is as follows:

```
0.146474] DMAR: [Firmware Bug1: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffffl, contact BIOS vendor for fixes [ 0.559347] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO.LPCB.H
EC.ECRD1, AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.5593801 ACPI Error: $ due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[ 0.5597301 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO.LPCB.H EC.ECRD1, AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330) [ 0.5597571 ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529) [ 0.559916] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO.LPCB.H
EC.ECRD), AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.5599401 ACPI Error: Aborting method _TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[ 0.560087] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO.LPCB.H EC.ECRD), AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330) [ 0.560111] ACPI Error: Aborting method _TZ. T201._TMP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
/dev/sda2: clean, 533199/61022208 files, 45401086/244059136 blocks
```

My laptop is an HP 250 G5 model. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the machine continue to boot and everything works OK?

Comment: Yes. Apart from this initial error message, everything works OK. I was hoping that something simple, like a configuration file change, would eliminate this message.

Comment: If everything is working ok ignore this know issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: turn acip off in your BIOS or grub configuration. FMI:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348806/acpi-exception-ae-not-found-infinitely-on-startup