# Problems booting with ACPI BIOS errors

Tags: boot

I am having problems booting Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Ubuntu is installed on its own SSD.

I selected to install 3rd party applications so my GPU drivers would install easier. I added the secure boot keys so I can dual boot with safe boot.

```
NVIDIA GTX 1070 8GB
Intel Core i7
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz 
32GB RAM dual channel
```

[image: picture of screen of text]

Comment: Have you *ever* been able to boot Ubuntu? If not, start over. [Verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu), then [follow the official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you still have problems, reference the tutorial when asking.

Comment: I have booted ubuntu befour but this is a new clean install with added safeboot key in Bios

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. I'm talking about *this installation*. A prior installation would not be relevant to your current problem. If that's the case, please follow the rest of my advice and start over. There's no sense in trying to rescue an installation that has never worked.

Comment: I have reinstalled it same problem, the USB was checked 2x with Rufus be-four loading the ISO on it, is it possible to try to downgrade to a erlyer Ubuntu trow recovery console?

Comment: Also regarding the guide, my laptop is not in the list of confermed machines.

Comment: Also i have followed the guide

Comment: Got it to work with a new relese 22.10 thanks for all help have a good weekend :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Yhe i have acelly removed the ethernet adapter in the laptop sence the antenna is borken, so makes sence thanks a lot :D