# AE_NOT_FOUND error appearing on Ubuntu startup

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, acpi

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS that works in dual boot with Windows 10, and recently this message started to appear on startup:

> [0.468124] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
> [0.468143] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psargs-529)
> [0.468282] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
> [0.468300] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psargs-529)
> [0.468454] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
> [0.468472] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psargs-529)
> [0.468691] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
> [0.468711] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psargs-529)
> [0.469039] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
> [0.469064] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psargs-529)
> [0.469439] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
> [0.469466] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psargs-529)
> [0.615035] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

And today I was stuck on this message for a long time:

> (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
> [0.963736] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
> /dev/sda4: recovering journal
> /dev/sda4: clean, 1168891/3203072 files, 12169237/12800256 blocks
> [34.234125] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f

After getting into recovery mode and updating the grub bootloader and repairing the broken packages I was able to get into Ubuntu, I still haven't rebooted to test if it worked and if it stopped showing these logs on boot.

Comment: After you reboot come back and update the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)