# ACPI BIOS Error in Ubuntu 20.04- Acer E15

Tags: 20.04, bios, acpi

I am new user of Ubuntu 20.04, and recently I have been encountering these ACPI BIOS Error on my Acer device when I start it. I am not sure on how to fix it. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: If the computer boots and you can login without error, ignore. This is a known issue that is being worked on.