# acpi error when booting up Ubuntu (with pictures)

Tags: boot

exactly what the title says

it worked fine yesterday and all of a sudden it can't boot up thia morning ?

Here are the pictures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjOOf.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1QMd.jpg)

Comment: Hi, could you provide a little more info. What version of ubuntu are you using, kernel-version, CPU and if you made any update previous to this error. Thanks

Comment: KERNAL 5.15.0-52-generic

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHZ

Comment: updated using sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade just yesterday

Comment: I've tempered alot of the ssh files (since I'm learning and new to ssh) but its not relevant here is it ?

Comment: Those errors are irrelevant to not being able to boot, something else is wrong. Can you confirm it won't boot even if you wait? It stays on that screen forever? Or does something else happen?

Comment: see [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: I have been having it  on for hours now, I can safely say that it won't boot

Comment: now the acpi error is gone, I turned acpi=off.

Comment: what's left is the /dev/sda5 clean: ***/*** files , ***/*** blocks

Comment: I'm very close now . . . update you guys soon ! (hopefully)