# ACPI Error while booting ubuntu

Tags: boot, kubuntu, bluetooth, acpi

I am beginner linux(Ubuntu) user. I don't know why I am getting these error.[Please check errors images here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeUEt.png)

Comment: Try using the search function here...https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)