# Syslog is flooded by ACPI error induced by kernel

Tags: acpi, syslog

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (kernel version 5.15.0) on Dell Inspiron 15 5510, and I found that the battery lifetime became significantly shorter since some time this month. Sometimes the computer will not shutdown or suspend properly, and the content of syslog flooded the screen before the computer reboots.

I looked through the syslog and the following error occurs repeatedly, dozens of time each second:

```
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L69]
```

I searched for some solutions on Google, but none of them seems to work, including upgrading BIOS and modify `/etc/rc.local` (which does not exist on my laptop).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @Pilot6 I have solved the problem by updating the kernel yesterday.