# Ubuntu won't boot up after a couple of months

Tags: boot, acpi

I have a Dell computer and went from Windows to Ubuntu. After a couple of months it won't boot. I reinstalled from a USB stick, then after a couple of months the same thing happened. I get this error message regardless of whether it boots or not, it does seem like a lot.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? What I can do to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem. The ACPI messages are OK.

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Hardware might make sense as after i turn off after it has crashed the lights stay on. i will do a hardware diagnostic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/) and [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)