# /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 1133688/15597568 files, 14849580/62383360 blocks -> ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS error while booting

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, acpi

Getting below mentioned error while booting my ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
I have dual boot Ubuntu with Windows and this happened whenever I reboot or start my laptop .

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 1133688/15597568 files, 14849580/62383360 blocks
[3.083935] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECSI] (000000008030bc83) [EmbeddedControl] (20210730/evregion
[3.084031] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20210730/exfldio-261)
[3.084110] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.UBTC.ECRD due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/pspars
[3.085364] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.UBTC._DSM due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/pspars
[3.086749] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_acpi_dsm: failed to evaluate _DSM 2
s
```

It will be very helpful if someone can help out to fix this error also if someone can tell be the reason behind why it's happening.
Thank you.

Comment: Does the machine boot and work after the errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @David Yes the machine boot and work normally after these errors, there is one more 
 same type of error comes after this error.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes but I did not understand how to fix this error.

Comment: If the system boots properly, there is nothing to fix. You can try to upgrade BIOS, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: Other then the error that @karel has addressed the others are not really errors but info messages and can be ignored if the system boots and works OK. I have various parts of that same message on 2 of my older machines but not on the other 4.