# Ubuntu ACPI error on compatible hardware since 22.04LTS after june 22 update

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, acpi

I have been reading up on  LINUX.org/Ubuntu and this  forum about the sudden occurrence of APCI errors resulting in a situation where systems might or no longer boot, the latter being my situation.

What i learned is that itś considered "a problem that usually occurs when new hardware is involved¨. That assumption might be true to a certain extend, however it is NOT true in my case.

I have a desktop from 2014 with an ASUS motherboard with an AMD10 processor and 16GB of Ram (i mean it was previously compatible hardware). The bios is from American Megatrends dated 2013. I started with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and moved on to 16.04 LTS  then 18.04LTS ( which caused a lot of problems so i reinstalled with 20.04 LTS)  in June 2022 I reinstalled my PC with 22.04 LTS.   I never had any ACPI error during the Boot process.

Since october 2022 my PC has been playing up with ACPI errors during the Ubuntu boot process that flashed by and I couldn´t read and it died around last christmas.  worse imho it has killed a 2 TB (3.5")  HDD but my system disk an SSD is still working, but i cannot be sure about that.

Before my holidays in september  my PC  started without playing up, i mean before  i couldn´t get a cupper while booting, from october onward i could go away and take a shower while waiting for my PC to boot.
I have Ubuntu 22.04  on a stick and it doesn´t matter if I boot from the stick or the SSD  it takes time, bloody much time.

So I can categorically deny that the ACPI error  problem is linked to new hardware, imho itś linked to the way ubuntu 22.04  is looking at ACPI and i expect an update after june 2022 is the cause of the problem.

my next step is to go back to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  As a test i pout and iso image of the 20.04.1 LTS  that i downloaded in 2020 on a disk and booted,  and lo and behold  no ACPI errors ....
this begs the question what happened with the UBUNTU between 20.04.1  and 22.04 that might cause the ACPI boot problems on hardware that was compatible befor the advent of 22.04 ?

One of the solutions is to change the Grub config file  and add  noacpi, acpi strict or whatrever.  but i cannot get that done:
please can someone describe  how I can do thias after booting from a flahdrive/usb stick , how I get to that /etc/default/grub file on the SSD,  how I can edit it  and how to save it , then  how to pass it through the grub2 executable from a system that doesnot boots only  from a bootable USB stick

Please let me know what info you want about my setup to help you resolve

got am image of the ACPI error [image: screenshotacpi error]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the clear, readable, complete ACPI errors that you are encountering. Image or text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @user535733 i´ll try to collect a boot log but in the current state of affairs that might be overreaching as the machine doesn´t get into a workable state

Comment: @ArturMeinild the linked article reflects that a change of kernel happened, no new hardware, no hardware updates like flashed bios unless it happened by malware outside my control

Comment: Is anything not working? If everything is working, ignore the errors. I don't believe your issue has anything to do with ACPI.

Comment: @ArturMeinild AFAIC i don´t consider the emergency state  a working environment so my answer is no noting works,

Answer (score 0):

You can disable ACPI by setting the option `ACPI=off` in `/etc/default/grub`

If you cannot get into the system you can go to recovery mode by hitting ESC right after BIOS to get into grub and then go to Advanced options and select the recovery linux image. From there you should be able to drop into a root terminal.

You should have rw, but I am not super familiar with it on Ubuntu 20.04, if you dont have RW you can remount the drive by doing `mount` to list your mounts and find your root mount to remount as rw. to remount it you need to do `mount -o remount,rw <mount_path>` and if it is not `/` you can do `chroot <mount_path>`.

You can now modify `/etc/default/grub` and add `ACPI=off` in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line.

If you are using grub2 you can do `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and for regular grub you can run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

It is not recommended to turn of ACPI in normal instances, but this will answer your question for how to modify and turn off ACPI.

**Possible Solution**

I did a bit of digging into what i2c i2c-2 and SMBus issues are and I did find it is usually related to a kernel issue.

Here are how others have solved their problems...

**Solution**

Reference: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/i2c-i2c-2-smbus-timeout-at-boot-upgraded-to-new-kernel-5-0-0-21/19947

They seem to be able to get around the issues by adding this to `/etc/modprobe.d/sensors`

```
blacklist adt7475
blacklist hwmon_vid
blacklist it87
blacklist k10temp
```

Removing from `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

```
vhost_scsi
```

then followed up with `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Modified `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="initcall_blacklist=i2c_dw_init_master"
```

Followed by `sudo update-grub` but I would rather suggest doing `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

This got rid of the issue for them, but I cannot promise it will work here.

Let me know if this solved your issue so I can modify my answer to make this better to read.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Killian-Fortman

Comment: I still don't think the error is related to ACPI. The "real" error is SMBus timeout.

Comment: @DerekGiroulle I modified my answer with a possible solution found online. Please take a look and see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: thank you @killian-fortman  I give it a try if i can get a login  because  in the emergency mode I cannot login ..

Comment: @DerekGiroulle You should be able to do the above procedure in emergency mode. Press 'ENTER' to go into maintanence mode. You should be in as root.

Comment: I couldn´t get it to work  giving up on Ubuntu