# Ubuntu on Hp Victus 15

Tags: hp, acpi

Hey i recently installed Ubuntu on my Hp Victus 15 but after installation i was facing issue of black screen and tons of errors everytime i boot up ubuntu ACPI errors. so can you guys guide how to fix this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)