# Ubuntu boot error , dev/sda2 clean files blocks and ACPI Error

Tags: boot, partitioning, icons, acpi

I installed Ubuntu 22.4 on an HP laptop. When I turn on my laptop it first displays an error message, `/dev/sda2 clean files blocks` and ACPI Error. Then a few second later Ubuntu icon is displayed, although Ubuntu works fine.

[image]

Comment: First there is no version of Ubuntu 22.4 As for the MESSAGES you are seeing they are not errors but messages if the machine boots and works you can ignore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)