# Ubuntu gui won't start, disk full. Any way to clean?

Tags: disk-usage

I have hp thinclient T630 with 64ssd disk on which i run home assistant server on docker container.

It was working very well for half a year or so, today i noticed it is down. I figured my disk is so full it does not even load GUI. I can only access console.

I don't have much knowledge with linux, it took me quite some time to set everything up.

I've noticed that almost 50G of disk space is used by /var/lib/docker
I will attach images, is there a way to clear that up? Also is there a way to clone all data if i buy a bigger disk, so i don't have to re-install everything again? [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUWLP.jpg)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4m0X.jpg)

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXRJB.jpg)

Comment: are your docker containers stored in /var/lib/docker? if so, you need to check out why the container is filling so much space (tons of logs from a failing process, maybe?) and fix/delete the offending files.

Comment: I would say so. There are few in /var/lib/docker/containers, but most are under 1M, while one is 32G. How do i check that? I was using portainer to manage containers and do backups and stuff, but of course i cant access it now. I said it wrong that nearly 50G is used by docker. 32G is, rest of 45G is /var/lib/overlay2

Comment: With luck you can recover enough space to get the GUI working and go from there. Use the following commands in the console. To clear the apt cache: `sudo apt-get clean`. To remove any old kernels `sudo apt-get autoremove`. To clear older journal records. `sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=7d`

Answer (score 0):

First it looked like this:
[failed to boot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Yzp.jpg)
[failed to boot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s62x3.jpg)

Then after googling around and trying to free some space, the only way that freed around 2G of space was using docker image prune -a command. Prior to this my /dev/sda2 was 58/58G full, after it, it says 56/58G, but still shows 100% full.

But then upon restart, ubuntu also stops at loading like on first image here, but without any FAILED error. I can still get into console by ctrl+alt+f1/f2. But i can't get into that log on "failed to boot2" by pressing esc.

Did i mess something up that way?

About bios errors, i think it does not have any connection with this problem, i'm pretty sure that error was there all along since i got this PC, formatting it and installing ubuntu.

What should i do now? As a newbie i really don't know where to look next.

Comment: ACPI errors are usually nothing to worry about. They probably were there before. See this question and its popular answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot

Comment: I have already tryed, besides prune image those commands you said, but it only freed a bit of space. Now i am stuck here, as i said, only with these bios errors and gui does not load. Any idea what i should do now?

Comment: On the basis that it will boot if you can free enough space I’d try removing the Firefox snap temporarily. Try `snap list` to get the list of installed snaps and their precise names. Then `sudo snap remove <firefox-package-name>`

Comment: That did let me in gui, thanks. Can you please help me figure what is filling up my space and how to avoid that? How do i check that?

Comment: Figured it out. It was log from HA, i have most sensors set to teleperiod 10, which is 10s reporting time. Managed to figure it all out with chatgpt. Very useful, but also freaks me out where this technology goes. Anyways thanks guys for helping me out!