# How to resolve ACPI bios error while rebooting

Tags: boot, acpi

1.6538811 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol _SB.FURO), AE_N

object-220)

OT FOUND (20210730/dsuload2-162)

OT FOUND (20210730/4suload2-162) 1.6538891 ACPI Error: RE NOT FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps 1.6538931 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.FUR11, AE_N

1.6538961 ACPI Error: AE NOT FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps object-220)

/dev/nume0n1p4: recovering journal /dev/nune0n1p1: Clearing orphaned inode 11403297 (uid=125, gid=130, mode 0100600, size-50947) /dev/nume0n1p1: clean, 208403/30769152 files, 4555888/123074816

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)