# Ubuntu 23.04 ACPI Error AE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: boot, acpi, 23.04

I upgraded my ubuntu to the version 23.04 and now I can't boot.

What can I do?

I get a lot of:
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element

The update finished without any problems and was done directly from ubuntu. 
Currently, the startup remains stuck as shown in the below image.

Moreover I'm able to boot in recover mode. 
[image]

Comment: those errors are irrelevant, see [ACPI Error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot). We will need other information to figure out the issue. How did you upgrade? Did you stop in the middle somehow? Can you boot in safe mode? What happens that you can't boot: it just hangs in the middle of booting, or something else? Please give us enough detail that we can help you.

Comment: ...upgraded to what? 23.06?

Comment: @Esther I add the information that you ask.

Comment: in recovery mode, try to upgrade/update again. What did you upgrade from, and what steps did you take to do so? Can you get your apt logs while in recovery mode and paste them here?