# Facing multiple unknown errors when starting the computer

Tags: bios, acpi

I'm new to Linux and have installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 few days ago, now since yesterday I'm facing these unknown issues and my computer is not even logging in, I've seen some answers here but could not figuring out the solution,its different from other blinking error notification issues as my window is stuck at this and can't go further by any action. I've important files and data in c disk so reinstalling Ubuntu is also a problem, can someone put some light on it please..

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, its Ubuntu 22.04.2 for desktop

Comment: My misunderstanding as the website says its the latest _lts_ version..

Comment: Did you make any changes to your system during the last working session?  ie. install any additional packages, change configs etc, fail to shutdown normally etc.

Comment: Yes I installed softwares and updates, and it also failed to shut download normally a few times due to occasional load shedding, but it was working fine and also shutdown properly the last time..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: I don't know much about the operating system so I didn't changed any config settings

Comment: No still not sure, the screen is stuck at this so cant take any action to update uefi or anything..