# SGX disabled by BIOS in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bios, sgx

I am facing the issue that SGX is disabled by BIOS. I am using lenovo ideapad and there is no option for enabling SGX from the BIOS. I even updated the BIOS but the option is still not there. There are some other errors along with the SGX error.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZDFo.jpg)

I tried using nosgx as kernel parameter. It resolved the SGX error message but other errors are still showing.[Error  Message after using nosgx as kernel parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUd9s.jpg)

I am using dual boot with windows 10 and able to log in to windows. Is there any way to enable sgx from windows?

Comment: you can just ignore the message, it's just a warning not an error and everything will work fine.

Comment: see [ACPI Error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @Esther its not just a warning, the computer is stuck on the error message.

Comment: it is, in fact, just a warning, and if the computer is stuck it's because of something else., and it just so happens that the last *warning* it showed is the SGX message, so you think that's the cause of the non-booting.  what is the last thing that changed about your Ubuntu install? Or is it new?