# ACPI Error: Can't reboot or enter grub

Tags: 22.04, acpi, grubrescue

I got this error after updating and now I can't hard reboot with the power button nor can I enter grub.

Is there a way I can shut down my laptop?

MSI Z16.

[image]

Comment: When you have a problem on Linux and start diagnosing, it’s not unusual to see pre-existing ACPI errors that you hadn’t noticed before. Most ACPI errors are harmless https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot  They are also probably a distraction from the real issue you face. Can you clarify what you have done that causes a problem. Is your issue not able to shutdown or not able to boot?

Comment: Just did a sudo apt update. That was it.