# Boot problem: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALRE>

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, 23.04

I have upgraded my hardware and installed a new Kubuntu system 23.04 desktop. I got errors when booting but the system seams to run OK. Should I care about it? What may cause the error? Is it related to the nvidia based video card?

```
aug 05 11:03:56 plusic kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALRE>
aug 05 11:03:56 plusic kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)