# Install alongside Windows Boot Manager

Tags: 23.04, windows-11

I’m trying to dual boot Ubuntu 23.04 on my computer which currently has Windows 11 installed on it. I’ve freed up space for the installation and I’ve disabled Fast Boot and Secure Boot. I also keep getting ACPI BIOS errors. From what I’ve seen Nvidia cards tend to cause problem. I’ve already tried following instructions left on similar questions and I’m at a loss.

Comment: I don't see a problem? Nor a question. "I’ve freed up space for the installation"  you need  unallocated space, not free space. "I also keep getting ACPI BIOS errors."  we all have those.

Comment: I apologize for how unclear this is. I posted this in a hurry. My problem is that the “Install alongside Windows Boot Loader” option is missing. Also, by “free” I meant “unallocated.”

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Michael I have found that it is best for Ubuntu to do the partitioning for you this I find results in a perfect dual boot.  On setup let it find Windows and all should go well.  When I have done the partitioning myself it normally ends with having to run the boot repair program.  If it is dual drives ditto it should find windows but you will have to prompt it (help it) to find the new drive by not selecting the auto install.
Do not disable secure boot as that will cause problems.  Do a backup of your system and a repair/boot drive.  But above all **turn off TPM** as that could be a problem.