# logging in ERROR on Kubuntu LTS 22.04.3, ACPI BIOS Error(bug), AE already exists , ACPI Error

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, acpi

[0.160800]ACPI BIOS Error(bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPL1._PR0],AE_already_exists (20220331/dwsload2-326) **I've attached a jpg image**

I'm new in linux world. I love linux for its customization, freedom. But problem begins when it shows **ERROR**. Anyways I'm using/have been using/researching(how to use it like a pro/SuperUSER) Linux since April 2023. I've been facing a problem logging in to my KDE desktop (on Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) every time. I have installed it(KubuntuLTS22.04.3) again but facing this problem again. I'm using it on HP laptop which runs with Intel i3 1215U, UHD Graphics card, 8GB RAM, 512GB Samsung SSD.
**Please help me how can I fix it or is there any solution for it not to popping up this error when starting my laptop everytime. This problem appears everytime signing/logging in to the laptop even when I restart the system!!**
I'm  pretty sure I can solve it by terminal/root file editing/sudo command( if there any ways , please help me to fix it ) *is there any YouTube tutorial please mention*?
I'm new here! Please teach me how should I behave here!

the pop up screen:-[1st installation message, it hurts my linux experience(**picture1**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAClf.jpg)
[2nd installation error(**picture2**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPnmS.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)