# Bios boot problem

Tags: boot, system

since upgrading to 22.04 lts , I get the following message on trying to boot up

```
[    0.211953] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB._OSC.CDW1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
```

After a few attemtps it boots as normal
can anybody help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)