# Second Monitor shows BIOS errors after startup

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors

I have been using a second monitor with this computer for over a year and recently the computer starts up, shows BIOS errors on monitor 2 and behaves normally on monitor 1 booting into Ubuntu.

[image: The errors shown on screen 2 during startup and then forever more.].

The monitor is not faulty because this computer also has Windows installed and the Windows installation still uses the second monitor normally with no hardware changes.

The monitor that is being detected is plugged into the motherboard HDMI port and the monitor not being detected is plugged into the GPU HDMI port.

lshw -C display:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:136 memory:42000000-42ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff memory:70000000-71ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: AlderLake-S GT1
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:137 memory:41000000-41ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:45000000-4bffffff
```

Comment: that's not "BIOS errors", it's just normal in the process of booting into Ubuntu, see [ACPI error on every boot(https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot). Does the computer boot up properly and work if you wait a bit?

Comment: @Esther yes the computer behaves normally but only uses one of the monitors attached to it and just shows that message on the other monitor (and nothing else) until shutdown...

Comment: hmm, seems that the issue is that your Desktop Environment isn't using the other monitor for some reason, and it's stuck in, essentially, a terminal. Does it show up in the monitor settings? what if you disconnect and reconnect the monitor before booting, or after booting?

Comment: @Esther no it does not show up in display settings, and now that I disconnected it while the computer was off, it doesn't show anything anymore... but remember, it works perfectly normally on Windows.

Comment: it's connected now? Can you restart with it connected (possibly twice)? are you using an nvidia card? If so, can you try "safe graphics" from grub, or reinstall the nvidia drivers?

Comment: @Esther yeah it's connected now.  I am using an nvidea card but not grub.  The bios has 3 graphics settings: "Initiate Graphic Adapter" set to PEG, "Integrated Graphics Share Memory" set to 60M and "IGD Multi-Monitor" which is set to Enabled.  Now that I think about it, the Windows that is able to use the monitor has some nvidea control panel

Comment: @Esther I also just did software update then restarted but nothing is changing

Comment: can you add output of `sudo lshw -C display` to your question? sounds like you have integrated and dedicated graphics and possibly Ubuntu is using the wrong one/using them incorrectly

Comment: @Esther I added the output to the question.  It may be relevant to add that the monitor that is being detected is plugged into the motherboard HDMI port and the monitor not being detected is plugged into the GPU HDMI port

Comment: that is indeed relevant information, add that to the question

Comment: @Esther ok added, do I need some kind of software from the GPU manufacturer to detect the monitor?

Comment: You can try installing the Nvidia driver and see if that helps, you also might need some other configuration because you have integrated graphics also and you basically need Ubuntu to use both, which it doesn't really like to do iirc. `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` should automatically install the correct nvidia drivers

Comment: @Esther "All the available drivers are already installed."

Comment: ok, but the card is using noveau, not the nvidia drivers. I'm not really an expert on Nvidia cards, but you can try searching up how to make your card use the nvidia drivers. or how to handle an Ubuntu system with both integrated and dedicated graphics

Comment: @Esther surprisingly, the ingrated and dedicated graphics is not the issue.  I just plugged the monitor not being detected into my other one and it still does not work

Comment: @Esther changing ports and wires both did not help