# ACPI errors - Ubuntu 22.04 - Lenovo

Tags: boot, 22.04, lenovo, acpi

Freshly (clean) installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IMH05.

Everytime I boot I get the following message before the log in screen :

```
[    0.202234] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.I2C2.TPD0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
[    0.202303] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
[    0.202296] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.I2C3.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
[    0.202254] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
```

Additional info:

- Kernel version : 6.2.0-26-generic
- BIOS Version: EGCN33WW & release Date: 12/24/2020
- Ubuntu installed from a USB (BalenaEtcher & Rufus) => in both cases the message appeared before logging in
- According to `dmidecode` output BIOS is upgradeable, but in the official site of lenovo I cannot find any relevant info/files

What could be the possible reason for these messages ? And what would be the possible solutions ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @Esther Not really. I have read that post but I cannot update BIOS, I have the latest kernel given that I installed 22.04 two days ago and I cannot figure out which hardware may cause the problem (and I don't know how to do so). Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: The thing is that it isn't a problem, you can safely ignore those warning messages, they don't affect your system at all, they are just indications that your BIOS doesn't implement everything to the official spec (but Ubuntu can handle that just fine, it's telling you just FYI)

Comment: @Esther thank you for the additional information. I would like however to better understand the messages e.g. are the messages only hardware related ? How can I determine which hardware produces the error etc.  (PS  i will try to ignore these messages from now on :) )

Comment: The errors are related to your motherboard's firmware, not hardware. They indicate that the firmware's implementation of ACPI is not up to the official specifications. If a newer BIOS version implements ACPI fully, the errors will go away. Sometimes a kernel update will take away the messages, but that's only because in a newer kernel version, the devs realized that the messages are harmless and not a big deal, so they change the severity of the messages to "warning" instead of "error", and they are therefore not shown on the screen.

Comment: @Esther I see thank you again for your detailed answer. I will update my question if I find/be able to update BIOS or a new kernel version is available and the messages do not show anymore.